# How to handle keyboard language change while composing a mail in Outlook?

Tags: outlook, mapi

Is there any callback that gets called when keyboard language is changed in To, Cc, Bcc, Subject fields of outlook? What MAPI properties are used to change keyboard language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, neither MAPI or Outlook have hooks like that.
Why exactly do you need that? Why does it matter how the recipient name/address were entered?

Comment: I am able to change keyboard language for a IMAP profile in To and Subject fields. How is it handled? I am changing languages using the language bar.                                                       https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-between-different-languages-as-you-type-c179e420-1e69-4bf2-b43c-f563c76ee3a3#bm2

Comment: What is the problem that you are trying to solve? Why does it matter whether a user types a few characters in English, switches the keyboard to Russian, types more ,then switches to Chinese? Or just pastes a string with Unicode characters from the clipboard? When you access the data, Outlook Object Model will return Unicode strings regardless of how they were entered.

Comment: We have a MAPI service provider which connects to our own backend servers ( Not exchange server ). When a profile is created using this service provider, customer is not able to change keybaord language in To, CC, BCC,Subject fields where as keyboard language can be changed in Body. How to handle this ? Also when an IMAP profile is used, language can be changed.

Comment: Say: Customer is in English (United States) locale. He is not able to change to Hebrew using language bar in To, cc, bcc fields. Where as same can be changed to Hebrew in Body.

Comment: Does your provider expose the STORE_UNICODE_OK bit in the PR_STORE_SUPPORT_MASK property returned by the objects exposed by your provider?

Comment: "STORE_ANSI_OK" is set and not STORE_UNICODE_OK.

Comment: Yes, UNICODE is not supported. Is this the reason that  language change is not happening in To, CC, BCC, Subject fields?

Comment: I don't know, but that sounds like a likely answer.